# Storing Active Directory Data in .txt File

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I'm performing the following powershell command to store data of an active directory(Users and their groups) in the variable `$UsersPerGroup` :

```
$UsersPerGroup = Get-ADUser -Filter * -SearchBase "OU=Users,OU=ITE,OU=HQ,DC=idb,DC=iadb,DC=org" -Properties DisplayName, memberof | % {
    New-Object PSObject -Property @{
    UserName = $_.DisplayName
    Groups = ($_.memberof | Get-ADGroup | Select -ExpandProperty Name) -join ","
    }
} |Sort-Object UserName | Select UserName, Groups
```

So far so good until I exported the data to a .txt file, apparently the number of groups cannot fit in the window of powershell so it is represented as: "...", as a result when I exported the `$UsersPerGroup` variable to the .txt file, the data also gets stored like that.

For better understanding, lets see the top right of my screen in powershell and then in the .txt file:

[image]

[image]

I need all the data, because I will manipulate it.

Thank you so much in advance!

Comment: You can try piping the variable to `Format-List` and preview the output in the console then pipe to `Out-String`

Answer (score 0):

A ADDS user can be part of many groups. Dozens actually. I been in many scenarios in customer engagements where users have been in up 100 groups.

So, if you are in that situation or like it, you have to rethink your approach. It's never going for fit on a single line or display on the screen that way or to a text file.

You have to decide on a acceptable format to look at this much data. So, you need to list by group and list users, or by users and list groups. Depending on what PS version you are using, you can really do this...

```
Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership  -Identity $env:username | Select-Object Name
```

THough it cannot list indirect group memberships and can error with „Unknown Error“.

```
function Get-NestedGroupMember
{
    [cmdletbinding()]

    [Alias('gngm')]

    param
    (
        [Parameter(Mandatory,ValueFromPipeline)]
        [string]$Identity
    )

    process
    {
        $user = Get-ADUser -Identity $Identity
        $userdn = $user.DistinguishedName
        $strFilter = "(member:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=$userdn)"
        Get-ADGroup -LDAPFilter $strFilter -ResultPageSize 1000
    }
}

$UserList = "$env:USERNAME",'SQLAdmin'
ForEach($User in $UserList)
{
    Get-NestedGroupMember -Identity $User |
    Select-Object -Property @{Name = 'ADUser';Expression = {$User}},Name
    "`n"
}

# Results

ADUser          Name          
------          ----          
Administrator   Administrators
Administrator   Schema Admins 
Administrator   Enterprise Admins                                                             
Administrator   Domain Admins 
...


SQLAdmin        Administrators
SQLAdmin        Users                                                
SQLAdmin        WindowsServiceAccounts                                                        
SQLAdmin        SharePoint Servers
```

Or do the listing this way... to avoid the username being repeated, if it is just a display thing.

```
 # Get users with base properties and their group membership, display user and group name
 ForEach ($TargetUser in (Get-ADUser -Filter *))
 {
     "`n" + "-"*12 + " Showing group membership for " + $TargetUser.SamAccountName
     (Get-NestedGroupMember -Identity $TargetUser.SamAccountName).Name
 }

# Results
------------ Showing group membership for Administrator
Administrators
Schema Admins
Enterprise Admins
Domain Admins
...

------------ Showing group membership for Guest
Guests
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with the `Out-File` command because it is outputting the *console* output, and not streaming the data to the file like you expect. One solution (as @user4317867 points out) is to pipe the content through an `Out-String` to get what you want. I propose a solution here [Powershell - Creating Wide Tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35347768/powershell-creating-wide-tables/35350815#35350815)

```
$UsersPerGroup | Format-Table -Property * -AutoSize | Out-String -Width 50000 | Out-File -Path Users.txt
```

This, while solves the problem, gives you a giant wide text file. The better way to output the content is to use Add-Content:

```
$UsersPerGroup | Add-Content -Path Users.txt
```

This gives the full row of content, although it isn't formatted in a nice human readable format, e.g.:

```
@{UserName=Jplaudir8; Groups=group1,group2}
```

In my opinion, the best way is to export to CSV:

```
$UsersPerGroup | Export-Csv -Path Users.txt -NoTypeInformation
```

Answer (score 0):

To make an important general point:

> I need all the data, because I will manipulate it.

To persist (serialize) data for *later programmatic manipulation*, NEVER use `>`, `Out-File`, or `Set-Content` - you will invariable lose information.

`Export-Csv` will give you *machine-parseable* output, but it will lack *type information* and will generally not handled *nested* data well.

**The most robust persistence / serialization format that PowerShell offers is CLI XML, which you can produce with `Export-CliXml` and consume with `Import-CliXml`**.
This is *as close as you can get* to faithfully serializing / deserializing instances of any type, but even that method has its limitations.

---

[HAL9256's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51450268/45375) shows you how to solve the `>` / `Out-File` ellipsis problem (truncated values indicated with `...`) by specifying a large-enough `-Width` value, but as stated, you shouldn't use this format for *programmatic* processing.

Depending on your needs, `Export-Csv` *may* be sufficient; the up-side is that it strikes a balance between machine parseability and friendliness to the human eye.